# Joining lists with same elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's assume that we have the following three lists

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 0.1}, {3, -3.2}, {4, 4.1}, {5, 0.2}};
data2 = {{1, -3}, {2, -2.1}, {3, 1.2}, {4, -3.1}, {5, -3.1}};
data3 = {{1, 0}, {2, 3.3}, {3, 0.003}, {4, 5.2}, {5, 3.1}};
```

As we can see, in all three lists the first elements of each sublist are the same. Now I want to create a new list `data` containing the first elements of each sublist and the sums of the second elements, i.e.,

```
data = {{1, 2 - 3 + 0}, {2, 0.1 - 2.1 + 3.3}, {3, -3.2 + 1.2 + 0.003}, {4, 4.1 - 3.1 + 5.2}, {5, 0.2 - 3.1 + 3.1}}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use associations, not lists of pairs.

```
{asc1, asc2, asc3} = AssociationThread @@ Transpose[#] & /@ {data1, data2, data3};

asc1 + asc2 + asc3
(* <|1 -> -1, 2 -> 1.3, 3 -> -1.997, 4 -> 6.2, 5 -> 0.2|> *)
```

Look up [`KeyUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyUnion.html) and [`KeyIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyIntersection.html) for dealing with the cases when the set of keys are not exactly the same.

---

You may also use [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html), though I am personally not very experienced with this construct, so I will only show the simplest example:

```
{ts1, ts2, ts3} = TimeSeries /@ {data1, data2, data3};
```

Now we can do

```
tsSum = ts1 + ts2 + ts3
```

Convert back to a list:

```
Normal[tsSum]
(* {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}} *)
```

Most operations that one might want to do on time series data, such as `ListPlot` or `LinearModelFit`, will work without needing to convert the `TimeSeries` back to a list.

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I want a new list as it is described in my post.

Comment: You can convert the resulting `Association` to a list by doing `List @@@ Normal@myassoc`

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Why do you want a new list? My point is that it is usually much more convenient to use associations for this type of data. What's the next thing you want to do with that list? Can it not be done with associations? Often, not only can it be done, it's also easier to do. And as Carl said, converting back to a list is trivial. (See also `KeyValueMap`.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Values @ GroupBy[Join[data1, data2, data3], First, {#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} &]
```

> {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}}

Also (thanks WReach):

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[Join[data1, data2, data3], First -> Last,Total]
```

> {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}}

More generally, if the input lists are ragged lists:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[Join[data1, data2, data3], First -> Rest, First@*Total]
```

Comment: +1.  In the second case, we could write `GroupBy[..., First -> Last, Total]`.

Comment: Thank you @WReach. Updated with the suggested form.

Answer (score 3):

```
{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]] // Total} & /@ GatherBy[Join[data1, data2, data3], First]
```

> `{{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

```
{data1, data2, data3} // Transpose // Query[ All, Transpose /* {1 /* First, 2 /* Total} ]
```

> {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}}

Alternatively we can initiate the `Query` using `GatherBy` as suggested by C. E.'s answer:

```
{data1, data2, data3} // RightComposition[
    Apply@Join,
    GatherBy[ #, First ]&,
    Query[ All, Transpose /* {1 /* First, 2 /* Total} ]
]
```

Comment: +1. In the first example, we can combine the transpositions: `Transpose[{data1, data2, data3}, {3, 1, 2}] // Query[All, {1 /* First, 2 /* Total}]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) to do this,

```
combiner[patt : ({x_, _} ..)] := {x, Total[{patt}[[All, 2]]]}

MapThread[combiner, {data1, data2, data3}]
(* {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 0.1}, {3, -3.2}, {4, 4.1}, {5, 0.2}};
data2 = {{1, -3}, {2, -2.1}, {3, 1.2}, {4, -3.1}, {5, -3.1}};
data3 = {{1, 0}, {2, 3.3}, {3, 0.003}, {4, 5.2}, {5, 3.1}};

data = {#[[1, 1]], 
    Inactive[Plus] @@ #[[All, 2]]} & /@
  (Join[data1, data2, data3] //
     GatherBy[#, First] &)
```

[image]

```
data // Activate

(* {{1, -1}, {2, 1.3}, {3, -1.997}, {4, 6.2}, {5, 0.2}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short solution:

```
data = Rule @@@ Join[data1, data2, data3] // Merge[Total] // KeyValueMap[List]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using associations, but I would use [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge) to total them:

```
{ass1, ass2, ass3} = Apply[Rule, {data1, data2, data3}, {2}];

Merge[{ass1, ass2, ass3}, Total]
```

> <|1 -> -1, 2 -> 1.3, 3 -> -1.997, 4 -> 6.2, 5 -> 0.2|>